# Retrieve value by variable name in erlang function

Tags: erlang

Is it possible somehow to retrieve variable value by its name (name represented as string)?

```
% we are calling foo function as foo(3)
foo(Param) ->
    Var1 = Param * 2,
    % some magic code here which can evaluate 
    % "Var1" string to Var1's value (6)
    ok.
```

I want to implement (if it is possible) some kind of logger macro, like

```
Param = 3*4,
% This should write "My parameter value is 12" to log
?LOG("My parameter value is $Param").
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are very specific about about logging you can use existing library called lager. It is widely used logging library which uses parse_transform.

Comment: @Marutha I am not very specific about logging. I just want to have convenient way to log message (without writing a lot of tildes and brackets in code: `io:format("My parameter value is ~p~n", [Param]).`) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to log is to have formatting string and list of parameters. However your idea is achievable through usage of parse transform.

Comment: Thanks! Parse transform is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dmitry Belyaev for mentioning parse transform. 
Say we have logging code:

```
?dump("My parameter value is $Param")
```

What I need here is to parse variables within format string ("My parameter value is $Param") with some regular expression. This format string contains single var name (Param). And we need to insert io_lib:format function call (by transforming original AST) with modified format string:

```
print_message(io_lib:format("My parameter value is ~p~n", [Param]))
```

In result we can archive required behavior:

```
Bar = "hello",
Buzz = buzz123,    
?dump("Say $Bar to $Buzz"),
% => example:19: Say "hello" to buzz123
```

You can look at my implementation [here](https://github.com/zaretskysa/vardump/blob/master/example.erl)

Answer (score 0):

For toy problems you could use:

```
io:format("My parameter value is ~p~n", [Param]).
```

See [`io_lib`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html) and [`io`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html).

Alternatively:

```
error_logger:info_report/1
```

or other [`error_logger`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html) functions.

The logging library [`lager`](https://github.com/basho/lager) is commonly used.

Comment: Code like `io:format("My parameter value is ~p~n", [Param]).` is really annoying sometimes (all those tildes and brackets...) Thats why I would like to use simpler code like `?LOG("My parameter value is $Param")`

Comment: I see, though all your code will depend on your parse transform. Parse transforms can be hard to get correct, check out `parse_trans` (https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans). `io_lib` with all those `~`s helps with formatting, it separates the format from the data. The syntax you propose is "unusual" for Erlang code, but certainly readable.